# How to deselect the selected option in multiple select using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to deselect the selected option in multiple select based on the selected option's value

I have already tried

[jQuery remove selected option from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494191/jquery-remove-selected-option-from-this)
and

[jQuery remove options from select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518216/jquery-remove-options-from-select)

```
<select size="5" id="skills"  multiple>
  <option value="0">Choose - Skills</option>
  <option value="19">Analytics</option>
  <option value="20">Android</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="addskills" value="Add">


<div class="skill-text">
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#addskills').on('click', function(){
        $('#skills :selected').each(function(i, selected){
            var text = $(this).text();
            var value = $(this).val();
            $('.skill-text').prepend("<span class='removeskill' data-id='"+value+"'>"+text+"<i class='fa fa-times' ></i></span>");
        });     
    });

    $('body').on('click',".removeskill", function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        //$('body').find("#skills option[value="+id+"]").removeAttr("selected");
        //$('#skills :selected').find("option[value="+id+"]").removeAttr("selected");
        $('#skills :selected').each(function(i, selected){
            if($(this).val() == id){
               alert('inside if');
               $(this).removeAttr('selected');
            }
        });
    });
})
</script>
```

please see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sxf6v3mt/2/

Comment: instead of prepend use html then in click of `removeskill` call click event of `addskills`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use  `$("select option[value='"+id+"']").prop("selected", false);`

It will deselect option which has value set as `id`

```
$('body').on('click',".removeskill", function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $(this).remove(); // to remove that item from list
        $('#skills :selected').each(function(i, selected){
           if($(this).val() == id){
             $("select option[value='"+id+"']").prop("selected", false); // to deselect that option from selectbox
           }
        });
});
```

Try: https://jsfiddle.net/p1Lu83a2/

Answer (score 2):

You can clear the value of the select list like this

```
$('#skills').val('');
```

Answer (score 2):

set selectedIndex property into -1.

example: Pure Javascript

```
var a = document.getElementById('skills');
a.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$(this).removeAttr('selected');`, try setting it to `false` using `.prop()`.

```
$(this).prop('selected', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

try `$('#skills option').prop("selected", false);`

you juste need to use

```
$('#addskills').on('click', function(){
    $('#skills :selected').each(function(i, selected){
        var text = $(this).text();
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('.skill-text').prepend("<span class='removeskill' data-id='"+value+"'>"+text+"<i class='fa fa-times' ></i></span>");  
    });   
    $('#skills option').prop("selected", false);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the selected index to -1 (for select and multi select)

```
$("#skills").prop('selectedIndex',-1);
```